# how to create an instance of class and set properties from a Bag object like session

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, viewbag, activator

the class will be declared in `runtime` and `values` are stored in a `Bag` object like `session` or `ViewBag` . Now I want to create an **instance** of the class and set it's properties **using Bag data**  . I know that I should use `reflection` , but I don't know if there is any method **out of box** that does such things or I should **create one** ?

```
session["Foo"] = "foo";
session["Bar"] = "bar";

var instance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className));

instance = ? // how to set properties using session
```

the class is not available in design time and application has no idea what its properties are .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(className);
var instance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
PropertyInfo[] properties = myType.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    property.SetValue(instance, session[property.Name], null);
}
```

Comment: class in not available in design time , and application has no idea what its properties are