# how to populate an instance created by Activator.CreateInstance() method

Tags: c#, late-binding

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        testclass tc = new testclass();
        Type tt = tc.GetType();
        Object testclassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(tt);

        PropertyInfo prop = tt.GetProperty("name");

        MethodInfo MethodName = tt.GetMethod("set_" + prop.Name);
        string[] parameters = new string[2];

        parameters[0] = "first name of the bla bla";

        MethodName.Invoke(testclassInstance, parameters);

        Console.WriteLine(testclassInstance.GetType().GetProperty("name").GetValue(testclassInstance, null));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class testclass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

output error message is:

> Parameter count mismatch

i don't want to create constructor for testclass and pass parameters/populate like that. i want to populate its properties one by one.

plz link other useful instance populating methods. i know this is the silliest one.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why didn't you do the simple thing and use [prop.SetValue(testclassInstance,  "your string")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Your parameter array is too big: `string[] parameters = new string[1];` will fix it.

Comment: It looks like search engine you are using have trouble finding good content. Try Bing - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+set+property+reflection or Google - https://www.google.com/?q=c%23+set+property+reflection - both give linked duplicate as top suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this question: [how to create an instance of class and set properties from a Bag object like session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050995/how-to-create-an-instance-of-class-and-set-properties-from-a-bag-object-like-ses)

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(className);
var instance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
PropertyInfo[] properties = myType.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (property.CanWrite) 
    {
        property.SetValue(instance, session[property.Name], null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a `if (property.CanWrite)` before calling property.SetValue in case there are some properties with no setter.

Comment: Thanks @Koresh, I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as:

```
prop.SetValue(testclassInstance, "first name of the bla bla");
```